# attribute error on numpy import with python 2.7 and wxpython

Tags: python, import, numpy, pyqt

I am struggling to get an ide working for python 2.7 with numpy, scipy, matplotlib and wxpython/PyQt installed. Running the ide spyder throws up the message "module 'object' has no attribute 'core'" for numpy. Same message occurs while "from numpy import *" on IDLE.
Here is the whole message. Please help. Thanks!
    C:\Python27\Scripts>C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Python27\Scripts\spyder"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\spyder", line 2, in <module>
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 96, in <module>

from spyderlib.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\environ.py", line 17, in <module>
from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditor import DictEditor
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dicteditor.py", line 31, in <module>
from spyderlib.config import get_icon, get_font
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\config.py", line 27, in <module>

from spyderlib.utils import iofuncs, codeanalysis
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\iofuncs.py", line 61, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
import add_newdocs
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from polynomial import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as NX
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: The fact that this happens in IDLE means we can eliminate spyder (to keep things simple). It looks like numpy has been installed incorrectly, have you checked that all your libraries are 32 bit or 64 bit? I would recommend installing the binaries again from the developers and ensuring they're compatible.

Comment: thnx danodonovan! I have downloaded 32 bit from the sites and reinstalled many times. The installer gives no error. And then I find all the packages(numpy, scipy, matplotlib) intact in the "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" folder. I am using the PTK editor now.

Comment: ...but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Solved! The problem was 'import numpy' in IDLE was looking for numpy files in 'C:\users\appdata\Roaming\python27\Lib' folder although I had installed python in C:\python27. Deleting the 'python27' folder in '~Roaming' immediately solves the issue! Hope it helps people with this problem. Case Closed!